# How can sql server log space used be more than 100 percent?

Tags: ms-sql

We are seeing application errors (exceptions) that report the transaction log "**is full due to ACTIVE_TRANSACTION**". There are no pending transactions reported by `DBCC OPENTRAN`.

Running `DBCC SQLPERF('logspace')` I see that the log size is only 1.3MB but the Log Space Used is reporting 107.7%

This database is configured with a log file Maxsize of over 2 TB, the initial size is 2MB, with Autogrowth set to 10%. Recovery model is set to Simple.

How can the log space used be over 100%, and with this much space available, why would an exception be generated?

Answer (score 1):

### Look for the culprit(s)

You could run [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) and see who is running what and look over the logic of those running processes/active transactions. Check to see if any T-SQL queries can be optimized to run quicker or as smaller transactions so it'll release the unused free space in the log file more quickly for re-use.

---

### It's possible by design

> [**SQL Server Simple Recovery
>   Model**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/4/sql-server-simple-recovery-model/)
>
> Every transaction is still written to the transaction log, but once
>   the transaction is complete and the data has been written to the data
>   file the space that was used in the transaction log file is now
>   re-usable by new transactions.
>
> <sub>[source](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/4/sql-server-simple-recovery-model/)</sub>

I've seen cases where a long running transaction grew the transaction log enormously large in a `SIMPLE` recovery model setup. That transaction actually failed and it took just as long for it to rollback. So long running transactions, bad performing, or poorly written queries not optimized can cause this problem.

Once space is allocated to a `SIMPLE` recovery model database transaction log file with either **unused transaction log free space** or **per auto-growth from OS-level free space**, the transaction log file will retain the new space until a file shrink operation occurs e.g. `DBCC SHRINKFILE (database_log, 2048)`.

**Important:** When a file shrink operation occurs e.g. `DBCC SHRINKFILE (database_log, 2048)`, it'll only release the unused log space within the transaction log as free space back to the OS. Active running transactions written in the transaction log will not be released during a file shrink operation.

---

### Shrinking the log file

The problem with shrinking the log file is that the next time a huge transaction or poorly written query runs, the log file will fill up again and you'll need to repeat the shrink operation. Find and resolve the root problem for a permanent fix for this problem. In the meantime, continue shrinking the log file.

---

### Fix the root cause

The root problem is likely a query so determining who is doing what and reaching out to them and reporting the issue with your findings would put the pressure on them to fix their logic to not hose up the server disk space partitions; look at optimizing the logic to query tune for performance.

- > [Tracking Down the Root Cause](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/transaction-log-larger-than-data-file/)
  >
  > Sometimes the root cause isn’t a long running transaction – for
  >   example, it could be that someone set up replication, and never
  >   properly tore it back down. Start by checking [`log_reuse_wait_desc in sys.databases`](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/03/my-favorite-system-column-log_reuse_wait_desc/):
  >
  > ```
  > SELECT name, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases;
  > ```
  >
  > Keep in mind, though, that’s only a snapshot of why the log can’t
  >   shrink right NOW.
  >
  > Then, if you don’t find anything interesting in there, you can [log
  >   sp_WhoIsActive to a
  >   table](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/07/logging-activity-using-sp_whoisactive-take-2/)
  >   to catch when folks do a `BEGIN TRAN`, and leave their session open
  >   for hours. Look for long-running transactions, talk to the owner, and
  >   see if they can do their work in smaller chunks instead of one giant
  >   transaction.

---

- > ### [Log File Space Metadata](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1629/determine-free-space-consumed-space-and-total-space-allocated-for-sql-server-databases)
  >
  > `DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)` is an absolutely functional command if you
  >   are only interested in consumption of your database log files.  It
  >   provides the cumulative size for each log file for each database on
  >   the SQL Server instance as well as the amount of space consumed (as a
  >   percentage of total log file size).  ***A drawback is the fact that the
  >   results are an aggregate for the database.***  If you have multiple log
  >   files the results are displayed at the database level, not at the file
  >   level.
  >
  > While this DBCC command is handy when you are reviewing issues that
  >   arise out of inadequate log backup scheduling or incorrect log file
  >   sizing, it does not give you all the information you need to make
  >   informed decisions on sizing your log files, adjusting you backup
  >   schedule frequency or recovery model.
  >
  > <sub>[Source](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1629/determine-free-space-consumed-space-and-total-space-allocated-for-sql-server-databases)</sub>

Comment: @Gary You might consider not having the autogrowth set to 10% and hard code 100 MB or something like that instead. While 10% of 2 MB is not much, once you get up in the 10's or 100's of GBs, then 10% of that is much more. Rather than percentage, you might consider using a specific MB size for autogrowth instead. Also, the exception is due to the log being full or whatever; resolve that and you should resolve the exception you talk about.

Comment: @Gary You might consider looking over my [Automate capturing SQL Server activity with SP_WHOISACTIVE and SP_WHO2 via a SQL Agent job](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161752/automated-sp-whoisactive-sql-activity-capturing-issue/161830#161830) answer with more specific detail on setting up the automated activity capturing solution to a table in case that helps any.

Comment: See the **Log File Space Metadata** section too for further detail related to the results you see with `DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)`